# Running .htaccess from php + $_GET friendly urls + cURL issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, get, placeholder

I need to ask you how to run `.htaccess` from PHP because I'm making software, but I want to users can by languages setup their own names of links, but I can only do this in `.htaccess`, but in `.htaccess` I don't know how to get from PHP language and then use it to specify which patches will be existing. Also I want to make friendly URLs in PHP (from `.php?id=0` to `.php/id/0`).

And the last... cURL.

I saw that in one software, how I can using cURL read page text (I have link `my.ip.com/idk.php?id=3` and the id 3 from server will only say text "ok" and I want to get that text to PHP and use it)

Comment: you need to ask just one question per post, not 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You cannot run .htaccess with anything. It's config file for your web server.

2) Example of http://you.com/@username

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^@(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

then get `$_GET["username"]` in `profile.php`

3) You should make your own .htaccess `RewriteRule`

4) Small example about cURL.

```
<?php
$post = [
    'PostName' => 'PostValue'
];
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
?>
```